# What's the shortcut for Show/Hide Playlist in VLC?

Tags: shortcut, vlc

I checked VLC's preferences but it seems that Show/Hide Playlist is the only player's button that doesn't have any keyboard shortcuts in Mac OS X version. Is there any way to control that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Window Menu > Playlist…
 <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>P</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: Are you sure? Ctrl+L does nothing on my MBP (Sierra). I tested with VLC running fullscreen and windowed.

Comment: Maybe he was confused with Windows - on Windows Ctrl+L acts as `toggle playlist`

Comment: That's for WINDOWS